# Connected device is a device or an emulator

Tags: android, debugging, adb, bridge

I have a device that is connected to my PC. Is it possible to know this device is real phone or emulator using adb? If it is possible then how can i do it? Google and [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/help/adb.html) didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Every emulator is named like "5" something. The first one you create gets the name "5554", the second, at the same time, "5556" and so forth.

Comment: Why would you hook your phone up anyway?  Whenever I test, I just copy the apk to the phone and install it myself.

Comment: `adb devices` will print all the connected device. If it starts with "emulator", its an emulator unless you hacked into the emulator and changed it.

Comment: At my old job, I `grep`'d the output of `adb devices`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `adb get-serialno` to obtain the serial number of the device. On the emulator the serial number starts with `emulator-`.

Comment: No, you are wrong.
If I use Genymotion, device id will be ip address like this 192.168.57.101:5555

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-d` and `-e` options to adb.

Eg in a script, then you can use `adb -d shell true` which will return `error: no devices found` and a non-zero exit status if you have an emulator running rather than a device attached, or a zero exit status if a device is attached.

Similarly you could use `adb -e shell true`.

Comment: Or any other command rather than true if you want actual text output.